# Python: how to determine None in dataframe using map and lambda

Tags: python, pandas, nonetype

```
l = [1,2,None]
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":l})
```

When I display df, it gives me:

```
+---+-----+
|   |  a  |
+---+-----+
| 0 | 1   |
| 1 | 2   |
| 2 | NaN |
+---+-----+
```

I define the following function to detect None in column a

```
def helper(x):
    if x is None:
        return "it is None"
    else:
        return "it is not None"
```

When I use df.a.map(lambda x: helper(x)), it gives me:

```
0    it is not None
1    it is not None
2    it is not None
Name: a, dtype: object
```

In l, l[2] is None. After I put it into df, None becomes NaN. Then my function helper(x) does not work. Should I change None in the list l or modify helper(x)?

Comment: `None` is a `NoneType` object. `NaN` is a `float`.

Comment: `NaT` (not a time) is a datetime, etc.

Comment: Use `if x is None or np.isnan(x):` and handle both cases.